# Gulp watch file and beautify it on change?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, js-beautify

I am having some difficulty trying to watch files and beautify at the same time each time the file is saved (manually). I just upgraded to Gulp 4. With Gulp 3 I didn't have any problem applying this logic, if I am not wrong the watch task callback didn't consider a change to run the watch again in an infinite loop.

How should I achieve this **in the same file**?

```
function beautify_js(){
    return gulp
        .src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(beautify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'));
}

gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch('js/*.js', beautify_js);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the `beautify_js` task, here's how to give a set of callbacks to gulp-watch, which works both for gulp v3 and v4-alpha.

```
gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch("js/*.js", ["beautify_js", "another_task"]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Pejman but this is not solving the infinite loop problem. Also, as far as I know, the way to do that in Gulp 4 is different, its done with [gulp.parallel()](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpparalleltasks).